# Does the Cassandra Object Mapping API currently not support updates?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I am using the [Cassandra Object Mapping API](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/crudOperations.html) with Cassandra 2.1. In the API it looks like an **UPDATE** of a row is performed doing these steps:

1. getting the object (Mapper.get)
2. change the fields you want to update
3. save the object (Mapper.save)

which translates to a **SELECT** followed by a **INSERT**. Will the existing CQL3.1 **UPDATE** statement be supported at a later stage in the Cassandra Object Mapping API for partial updates? I want to avoid the initial read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use an `Accessor` for coding an update.
2. Transparent `save` vs `update` is either gonna be requiring using proxies and field interceptors (complex impl), or lead to actually hide the read-before-saving anti-pattern.

Using Accessors should give you everything's needed without making the mapping module perform magic behind the scenes.

This topic has been discussed here: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JAVA-474

Comment: Thanks Alex, i'll be watching that Jira to see what you guys come up with. I guess the `Accessor` is almost the same as writing your own CQL statement (which is very flexible). One problem with the `Accessor` syntax is that you statically define the columns to be updated correct? Example: `@Query("UPDATE users SET first_name=:first, last_name=:last WHERE id = :id")` I always need to update both `first` and `last` at the same time as far as I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

try this mapper 
https://github.com/valchkou/cassandra-driver-mapping

It supports partial updates including collections

```
mapper.updateValue(id, Entity.class, propertyName, value);

/** Append value to the Set, List or Map. */
append(id, Entity.class, propertyName, value);
```

https://github.com/valchkou/cassandra-driver-mapping#write

Also it has automatic Schema Sync feature (and few more features) missed in datastax mapper

Usage sample:

```
Entity entity = new Entity();
mappingSession.save(entity);
entity = mappingSession.get(Entity.class, id);
mappingSession.delete(entity);
```

available on maven central:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.valchkou.datastax</groupId>
  <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>          
</dependency>
```